# Releasing a new version of Google add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on an add-on for the new Google spreadsheets but I wonder how versions are handled? In the old script gallery, there were versions. Are they working the same in add-ons after the add-on is published?

Also I see an auto generated Help submenu item. How do I generate content for it?

Thanks.

---

Thanks to @Steve Lieberman answer I see now how to choose on publish and update later the version of the add-on. But in the documentation I can't find an explanation of what will be the effect of updating to a new version on already used copies of the add-on. Will they be automatically updated? Will they receive in some form a notification of the new version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your add-on [1], there's an option to select the version of the script that will be used.

Note there's also a version of the Chrome Web Store entry, this can differ from the version of the script.

The source code that is executed will be based on the version of the script that is published to the Chrome Web Store.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#publish_your_add-on

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know what will happen when the add-on is updated? Will the used copies be automatically updated?

Comment: They will be automatically updated, but users might continue running the old version until they refresh their document/spreadsheet window.

Comment: Hi @Steve Liberman, thanks very much. This is great news :) I wonder, is this behavior documented somewhere? Thanks again.

Comment: Updating a published Add-On to use a new Deployment/Version will immediately affect all documents using the Add-On, without any notifications.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new deployment/version of the script in the script editor.

Then **update the script version** in the Project's [Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk) page, *App Configuration tab* (scroll down), then Save it.

Note that the update will take effect immediately when Saved, including for documents that are currently open in a browser.

Debugging: I don't think it's possible to have multiple deployments/versions of a Published Add-On active at the same. You have to do your debugging of the HEAD version in the Add-On's Host document, or in a document that does not have the Add-On installed (you can add the HEAD deployment of the Project as a script library in that case).

[image]

[image]